# C: wrong allocation of the pointer

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2017, out-of-memory, heap-corruption

I have a char-array and I want to remove whitespace just before or after or both, the word (or phrase) and not in the middle.

For example:

"hello" --> "hello"

" hello" --> "hello"

" hello " --> "hello"

" " --> ""

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = " prova ";
    char *t = NULL;
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        t = NULL;
    }
    else {
        int n = strlen(s);
        t = malloc(sizeof(char)* (n + 1));
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            t[i] = s[i];
        }
        int k = 0;
        if (s[0] == ' ')
        {
            ++k;
            t = realloc(t, sizeof(char)*n);
            for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i)
            {
                t[i] = s[i + 1];
            }
        }

        if (s[n - 1] == ' ')
        {
            if (k == 1)
            {
                int j = 0;
                t = realloc(t, sizeof(char)*(n - 1));
                for (int i = 0; i <= n - 2; ++i)
                {
                    t[i] = t[i];
                    j = i;
                }
                t[j] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int j = 0;
                t = realloc(t, sizeof(char)*n);
                for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i)
                {
                    t[i] = t[i];
                    j = i;

                }
                t[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

The debugging does not give me error or other things, but I know there is a problem with memory and heap and I don't know how to remove it.

I looked for other questions similar to mine on this platform and they exist, but none of the answers solved my problem.

Please give me some advice, thank you

Comment: Seems convoluted. Note that `strlen` takes a linear pass over the string -- so why not do that pass yourself, using that pass to determine the number of leading and trailing spaces that you want to remove and then allocate the exact space that you need, rather than allocating and then reallocating?

Comment: @xing Oh yes you are absolute right, I had forgotten

Comment: @xing you are on fire!! Thank you

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't know how to do it

Comment: I have edit the code with your tips

Comment: it still gives me problems with memory, :-(

Comment: `sizeof(char)*n + 1` is a rather interesting expression...

Comment: What is `t[i] = t[i];` doing?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 
it only serves to see how the string flows during debugging

Comment: `sizeof(char)*n + 1` makes no logical sense.

Comment: @melpomene 
the string ends with zero which is not calculated by the `strlen` function, so I need to add that `+1`

Comment: "know there is a problem with memory" How do you know that?

Comment: @n.m. 
I know it because my professor has provided us with a personal compiler, and that compiler gives me that kind of error

Comment: "so I need to add that +1" You add one of what? 1 mile? 1 fortnight?

Comment: @n.m one byte of char

Comment: We cannot troubleshoot your professor's personal tools, sorry. Your program is invalid, just compile it with any standard compiler and watch the messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187394/discussion-between-n-m-and-kkkkk).

Comment: @n.m. 
My professor is an IT engineer, I'm a university student

Comment: " My professor is an IT engineer" What does it have to do with anything? You have your professor's tools. We don't. That's all that is needed to know about them.

Comment: unfortunately they are reserved only for university students because it is part of the online platform, nobody else can access it

Comment: So why are you bringing them up here then? They are totally irrelevant.

Comment: I brought the question on this platform because I wanted to know if there was any problem with the memory allotment. But as far as seen, it will be the fault of that compiler. That's all

Comment: Sorry if I made you waste time, I just wanted to know what the error was, it's hours I try to figure it out without results, so I turned to this platform.

Comment: @dandan78 thanks, 
I'll definitely take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of small errors in your code beginning with:

```
if (s == NULL)
```

`s` can never be `NULL` unless your compiler is completely broken or you have less than an 8-byte stack.

Next, you `realloc` before you remove the leading whitespace, e.g.

```
        t = realloc(t, sizeof(char)*n);
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i)
```

Which (if any) bytes are truncated by the call to `realloc` are not specified. Instead, you need to operate on `t` to remove the leading whitespace before calling `realloc` (and then you are still not guaranteed any memory will be adjusted)

Next, you call `realloc` multiple times, when you should simply operate on the original copy of `s` in `t` to remove both leading/trailing whitespace and then make a single call to `realloc` at the end. `malloc/realloc` are relatively expensive calls from an efficiency standpoint and shouldn't be called repetitively.

Rearranging the logic a bit, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = " prova ";
    char *t = NULL;
    size_t n = strlen(s);           /* strlen returns size_t */
    int k = 0;

    t = malloc (n + 1);             /* sizeof(char) is 1 */
    if (t == NULL) {                /* validate ALL allocations */
        perror ("malloc-t");
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++) /* copy s to t */
        t[i] = s[i];

    while (t[k] == ' ')             /* count leading whitespace */
        k++;

    for (size_t i = 0, j = k; j <= n; i++, j++) /* remove whitespace */
        t[i] = t[j];

    n -= k;                         /* update n */

    while (n && t[n - 1] == ' ')    /* remove trailing whitespace */
        t[n-- - 1] = 0;

    void *tmp = realloc (t, n + 1); /* realloc with tmp varaible */
    if (tmp == NULL) {              /* validate ALL allocations */
        perror ("realloc-t");
        return 1;
    }
    t = tmp;                        /* assign new block to t */

    printf ("t: '%s'\n", t);
    free (t);                       /* don't forget to free memory */

    return (int)n;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_trim_realloc
t: 'prova'
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/str_trim_realloc
==26078== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26078== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26078== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26078== Command: ./bin/str_trim_realloc
==26078==
t: 'prova'
==26078==
==26078== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26078==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26078==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 14 bytes allocated
==26078==
==26078== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==26078==
==26078== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26078== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: @DavidCRankin Thank you man, 
now I do not give any memory error, now I study your program for good to understand how you have solved it, thanks again

Comment: Sure. Glad to help. The easiest way to work with this type problem is to take out a pencil and paper and draw the characters in `t` out on paper. Then you can see and verify what you need to do with each character in each loop iteration. That really helps keep the indexing straight. When I was learning, I would just use a small box around each character to represent each character in a string and write the index below. Makes it a lot easier (and less error prone) than trying to do it all in your head `:)`

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways of doing this:

- First: Trim original variable inside other variable, so there are two variables: first variable have a string with whitespaces and second string will be the content of first varaible without start/end spaces.
- Second: Trim the variable inside itself.

The code which do that is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t trimInOtherVariable(char *out, size_t len, const char *str)
{
  if(len == 0)
    return 0;

  const char *end;
  size_t out_size;

  // Trim leading space
  while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
  {
    *out = 0;
    return 1;
  }

  // Trim trailing space
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace((unsigned char)*end)) end--;
  end++;

  // Set output size to minimum of trimmed string length and buffer size minus 1
  out_size = (end - str) < len-1 ? (end - str) : len-1;

  // Copy trimmed string and add null terminator
  memcpy(out, str, out_size);
  out[out_size] = 0;

  return out_size;
}



char *trimInSameVariable(char *str)
{
  char *end;

  // Trim leading space
  while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
    return str;

  // Trim trailing space
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace((unsigned char)*end)) end--;

  // Write new null terminator character
  end[1] = '\0';

  return str;
}



int main(void)
{
    // Declare string for trimming
    char buffer[] = "    pr ova    ";
    size_t size;

    // Declare pointers which will store trimmed variable
    char *stringWithSpaces = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)+1) );
    char *stringWithoutSpaces = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)+1) );

    // Check if allocating memory is OK. Then copy string to trim inside pointer
    if (stringWithSpaces == NULL || stringWithoutSpaces == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        strcpy(stringWithSpaces, buffer);

    // Way 1: Trim 'stringWithSpaces' inside 'stringWithoutSpaces'
    size = trimInOtherVariable(stringWithoutSpaces, strlen(buffer), stringWithSpaces);
    // Way 2: Trim 'stringWithSpaces' inside itself
    stringWithSpaces = trimInSameVariable(stringWithSpaces);

    // Show trimmed strings
    printf (
        "String trimmed in other variable: \"%s\"\n"
        "String trimmed in same variable: \"%s\"\n"
        , stringWithoutSpaces, stringWithSpaces
    );

    // End function
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: thank you, your program works, now I'll try to figure it out to fit my schedule, thanks again

Comment: I put +1 on the answer, but I accepted David's answer because it was more explanatory than yours. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has at least these errors:

1. `#include` directives are missing. You need `stdlib.h` and `string.h` at the very least.
2. `main` is declared to return `int`, but you are returning `NULL` from one place and `t` (which is of type `char*`) from another place.
3. It may or may not do what it's supposed to do. It only removes up to one space in the beginning and one in the end, not all spaces before or after the phrase, and does so in a needlessly convoluted way.

One kind of error this program does not seem to have is writing data past the end of anything.

Comment: I forgot to put the directives here in the questions, but in my pragram there are, now I edit

Comment: For the second point you are right, now I edit

Comment: For the third point  how do I work to solve it, can you give me some advice?

Comment: Three steps: 1. *Find* all the spaces at the front of the *original* string. 2. *Find* all the spaces at the back of the *original* string. 3. Make a *new* string to accommodate what's left, and make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You must free 't' before the end of the program. Maybe you need a little refactoring in your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> //realloc
#include <string.h> // memcpy

char *remove_space(char *s) {
  char *t = 0;
  if (s == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    int n = strlen(s);
    t = malloc(sizeof(char) * n + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
      t[i] = s[i];
    }
    int k = 0;
    if (s[0] == ' ') {
      ++k;
      t = realloc(t, sizeof(char) * n);
      for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i) {
        t[i] = s[i + 1];
      }
    }

    if (s[n - 1] == ' ') {
      if (k == 1) {
        int j = 0;
        t = realloc(t, sizeof(char) * n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 2; ++i) {
          t[i] = t[i];
          j = i;
        }
        t[j] = 0;
      } else {
        int j = 0;
        t = realloc(t, sizeof(char) * n);
        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i) {
          t[i] = t[i];
          j = i;
        }
        t[j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return t;
}

int main(void) {
  char s[] = " prova ";

  free(remove_space(s));

  return 0;
}
```

Check with valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./program
```

```
==8753== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8753== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8753== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8753== Command: ./program
==8753== 
==8753== 
==8753== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8753==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8753==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 21 bytes allocated
==8753== 
==8753== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8753== 
==8753== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8753== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: @luisfeliprebraga What is valgrind? I never heard of it

Comment: Valgrind Memcheck is a memory error detector tool --> http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Comment: ok thank you for this thing